# how can i connect the blocks without a button , but a spot on the box where we can drag the arrow from one box to other

Tags: angular, angular6, jsplumb

I wanted to connect the div's using a line manually but not with a button. When the user wants to connect with a line , he should able to drag an arrow from one to other box

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jsplumb?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

go through the link

i want to connect the divs manually without a button

thanks in advance

Comment: I know your question is a bit a old, but did I answer your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set endpoints to your elements in order to do drag/drop connectors and tell which endpoint is source and which is target. So, you need to use `addEndpoint` function this way :

```
this.jsPlumbInstance.addEndpoint("Source", {
  anchor: "Right",
  connector: ['Flowchart'],
  isSource: true
});
this.jsPlumbInstance.addEndpoint("Target1", {
  anchor: "Left",
  connector: ['Flowchart'],
  isTarget: true,
  endpoint: "Blank",
});
```

I updated your [Stackblitz with my answer](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jsplumb-y4f9vq?file=app/app.component.ts).

More informations in [official documentation](http://jsplumb.github.io/jsplumb/endpoints.html).